# Email bank account information from form

Tags: php, forms, security, bank

A client wants a registration form on their website which contains, among other fields, spaces for bank account information (including sort code and account number). The form will not submit the data to a database, so there is no storage of this information, but it will email the client with this information.

My question is, what are the security issues with emailing bank account information, and are there any accepted protocols / methods for maximising security?

Comment: Just curious why this was voted down? Badly phrased?

Comment: You might get a more relevant answer over at the [Security StackExchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data security is vital for everybody dealing with payment data, because nothing is more important than keeping this kind of data as secure as possible. Bank account information definitely are to be dealt with highest care.

> What are the security issues with emailing bank account information?

Well, everybody with access to this email (may it be the email provider or whoever is hacking into the SMTP traffic) can read the data. Therefore it is a big security issue, since you cannot control who has access to this. And you have even less control over what people do with this data.

Advice is not very easy to give here, this highly depends alot on what you have to code and which is the system enviroment, therefore my advice is only in a very general sense:

- Don't send bank information data via email.
- Use highly encrypted methods (SSL/HTTPS).
- Always have control over who has access to this kind of data.
- Ask questions, like: *If you don't want to store the data, to what purpose do you want to send it via email?*

This list can go on and on.

There are some very extensive standards out there. For this kind of data, I recommend following the advices given in [PCI DSS](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/). Its main purpose is protecting card data, but its recommendations are also applicable to other topics.

Comment: Thanks -- looks like this point: "Don't send bank information data via email" is key. I can only assume the (potential) client is not concerned about this... I'll ask in the Security Stack Exchange too as J.Kommer suggests, but it sounds like there's no secure way of doing this.

Comment: ...actually, anybody on the same LAN as any of the nodes the SMTP message apsses through can read the email. This is so *phenomonally* dangerous that you may be liable for damages arising as well as the customer you are implementing this for!

Comment: @symcbean Aye, true, but I didn't want to delve too deep into all aspects at once. The issue at hand is a big no-no, this should be the essence of my reply! :-)

Comment: Ok, I'm definitely not doing this -- thanks for the advice all.